# android sax not parsing "dc:creator"?

Tags: android, xml, sax

Hope someone can provide some guidance - i've been using android sax parser with several feeds. Now when I want to parse an item that contains following:

```
<category>category</category>
<dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">creator</dc:creator>
<dc:date xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">2011-10-13T07:00:15Z</dc:date>
<geo:lat>51.95271682739258</geo:lat>
<geo:long>-0.21096819639205933</geo:long>
```

I can get the value of "category" tag, but nothing for the others.

The code used follows examples from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/, in particular snippet to parse the tags:

```
Element item = channel.getChild("item");

item.getChild("category").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
  public void end(String body) {
   Log.e("mydebug","cat>>"+body+"<");
  }
});
item.getChild("dc:creator").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
  public void end(String body) {
   Log.e("mydebug","creator>>"+body+"<");
  }
});
```

generates this output:

```
10-13 14:13:12.763: ERROR/mydebug(609): cat>>category<
10-13 14:13:12.763: ERROR/mydebug(609): cat>>category2<
```

I'm using the following:

```
import android.sax.Element;
import android.sax.EndElementListener;
import android.sax.EndTextElementListener;
import android.sax.RootElement;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;
```

Anything I'm missing?
Only thing I can guess is that ":" in the tag is giving me problems, but I couldn't find any examples of similar issue.

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried `item.getChild("creator")`?  Perhaps it is only looking up by localname rather than namespace + localname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the startElement() and endElement() methods in your DefaultHandler, both the local name and qualified name values are passed in.  Make sure you're checking the qualified name for things like 'dc:creator' or else they won't match.

See the official documentation here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29

Also, you may consider using the XML Pull Parser as it's a bit more light weight than SAX and might be more appropriate for your needs:  http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory.html

Comment: thanks - I completely missed that - works like a charm :) will look at the pullparser as well - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using an API that only looks at the localname of the element:  [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/sax/Element.html#getChild%28java.lang.String%29)

Try this instead:

```
item.getChild("creator").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
  public void end(String body) {
   Log.e("mydebug","creator>>"+body+"<");
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Nicholas - I tried that before but it didn't work so I missed that it is a local v qname. works with "item.getChild("http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/","creator")"