# Parsing with special character XML

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, special-characters

I have a problem to obtain my feed xml.The problem is that when the tag doesn't contain a special character like "content", i have no problem. But when I have “:” in my tag like "d:content", my parser doesn't work.

My question is : What can i do to make it work ?

I found that link :[android sax not parsing "dc:creator"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755859/android-sax-not-parsing-dccreator) which is a similar problem, but i don't understand well the documentation

Thanks

[url of my xml](http://wcf.tourinsoft.com/Syndication/cdt43/69e53dfc-1433-4a15-ba1a-38a3d838c3d2/Objects?$top=2)

Answer (score 1):

It's an XML namespace. Your parser is probably complaining that it cannot knows what the 'd:' is mapped to. You could also tell your XML parser to ignore namespaces, if you don't care about that. Could you post your complete XML to make things a bit more clear, in case my suggestion doesn't work for you?